# Blackberry webworks compatiblity

Tags: java, html, blackberry

I am about to develop a Webworks app. From the docs, it is almost clear that it can work only on devices with **os 5.0 and above**. But I just want to know, if there is any way by which the app can be made to work on devices running **OS less than 5.0** ?

I thought of trying it out myself before asking it here. I have created a Helloworld webworks app, generated the cod file, signed it and then tried to install it on a device with os4.5 using javaloader.

And i got an error saying **The specified module was rejected by the device and cannot be loaded**. I cannot find much info about this error. Can you guys confirm it is because lower os versions doesn't support webworks API.?

Answer (score 3):

Your webworks application runs into a [BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html) instance.

You as a WebWorks developer do not deal with BrowserField instance, but your application, to be launched and work, needs this new BrowserField class implementation that supports the necessary functionality.

Older device software does not support the functionality that new BrowserField provides.
And due to this fact it is not possible to launch WebWorks application on devices with older OS-es than 5.0.